# Smooth Shading option not working

Tags: modeling

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q3kcN4hKMkdARc4XzEbYOsSwoWuhSzKA/view?usp=sharing

Here's my Blender File

I can make the object active.

But when I click the smooth option, nothing happens.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like most of the faces in the model are disconnected. When you activate smooth shading on disconnected faces, Blender treats each one individually and it looks like flat shading because each face's boundary is handled independently from its neighboring faces.

It's best to model (or import) objects with connected faces if you want to use smooth shading, but here is a quick and dirty way to join most of the faces in your model:

1. Select the object.
2. [TAB] into Edit Mode.
3. [A] to select all vertices.
4. Mesh > Vertices > Remove Doubles

This will join most of the faces and you will get smooth shading for the most part. You will probably need to manually repair some faces to get it working across the entire object.

Answer (score 4):

Click on Clear Custom Split Normals Data under Geometry Date,
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Go to Vertex Tab and uncheck Auto Smooth

[image]

Go to Edit Mode Press <kbd>W</kbd> Remove Doubles

Now u have loose the geometry or unfill Faces

Select all and Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> Flip Normals

Now click on Smooth Shading.

[image]

Comment: This is a better fix than what I offered.

Answer (score 2):

I can just add that for me it was ambient occlusion that gave the illusion of flat shading. Someone else might run into the same issue.

Comment: yes me too i just googled about this problem. ambient occlusion was the culprit. but only certain areas got affected by ambient occlusion in my case on my face mesh. does that mean it is bugged?

Answer (score 1):

Many times people forget it but you have to **select** model in object mode and then press *shade smooth*

Comment: I can't believe I was missing that.

Answer (score 1):

My issue with 'shade smooth' not working was that I had a bevel modifier. I just removed it and immediately my mesh became smooth. It turns out the the 'shade smooth' funtion was actually applying, it's just that the effects of the bevel modifier had higher priority.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this myself and wondered, why this would happen since my mesh was perfectly fine. In order for the smooth shading to be applied to the entire mesh, you have to select it first by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> in Edit Mode.

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>F3</kbd> and type `Shade Smooth`

Answer (score 0):

The only thing everyone is missing and what was in my case is that you need to double check if your normal map image texture is set to non-color color space.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)