# How to make such a strange file has no active object?

Tags: modeling, scripting, file-format

I have gotten a [blender file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94209/smooth-shading-option-not-working) confused me with two issues.
This time I will ask about one of them.

The file has three objects, Camera, Lamp and Face. 
In object mode, selectecd objects has bee "Face" only. 
But active object is nothing!
How can I make such a file that has no active object?

[image]

Comment: Type `C.scene.objects.active = None` into console, and "bingo" no active object.  To be in selected objects, then `obj.select is True`.

Comment: There won't be any active object in the scene e.g. after deleting any object. As bottom Outliner is set to show active objects it doesn't show anything. Top Outliner on the other hand does.

Comment: @Mr Zak Thanks. I could make such a strange scene without using a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to make the scene without any active object.**

Since the issue is solved, I will explain by myself.
 
Consider the case where are two objects "Cube" and "Cone" exist. 
"Cube" is selected and on the first layer. But the layer is turned off. On the other hand, "Cone" is active and on the second layer turnd on. 
When "Cone" is deleted, active object will be None. However, "cube" is still selected. 
If you turn on the second layer, the scene is completed.

[image]
[image]